# Help me identify a movie with a son and a daughter looking for their father on another dimension/world with 3 suns?

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I need help identifying a movie which I've been looking for for the last maybe 10 years, without any success. The information I remember about the movie are as such:

1. The father was conducting some experiment and was this way transported to this other dimension/world, and when the police investigated his lab, a woman came with the results from the lab which said they found a dust-like substance that was some billion years old, with the test's accuracy being at some million years give or take.
2. The father's son and daughter somehow went to this other world, and there were greeted by someone I think, but they definitely saw 3 suns there when they arrived.
3. That someone who greeted them took them to the place where their father was held, it was a state building where everyone was supposed to act like robots, soulless and such and so did the children in order not to be caught.
4. The children found their father, and that's either where my memory ends or I stopped watching.

I watched this movie when I was a kid, on the early classes of elementary school I believe. I am currently 22 years old. However, I'm not entirely sure whether it was in English, or I watched it on German satelite tv. But a lot more possible that is was in English.

Thanks in advance to anyone that takes the time to help me out even in the slightest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That sounds exactly like [A Wrinkle in Time](http://imdb.com/title/tt0290382/)! The father was doing a dimension-jumping physics experiment and disappeared, so his kids had to enlist the help of some local friendly aliens to go find him.

Comment: As soon as I saw your answer I jumped out of bed to look for this movie. I couldn't possibly thank you enough, you have no idea of the service you have done me, I've been looking for this movie ever since it came out, and you gave me the answer in less than 2 hours. Best of luck to you, glad to be a member of this community.

Comment: I didn't even know there already was a Wrinkle in Time movie until you asked! I guess they did a good job of following the story from the book.

Comment: This was what I suspected but I couldn't verify it because there's no scripts and that "dust" portion threw me for loop. Cheers.

Comment: The movie did change a few things (some of which didn't really seem necessary to change, but I guess provided for a more "exciting" movie), but in general was true to the book.

Comment: @ChrisKarampeazis, if you haven't read the book, I'd *highly* recommend reading it.  An all-time classic.

Comment: @Wildcard as soon as I've finished what I'm currently reading, I'll start looking for it. Thanks for the suggestion